# JaVers, query state of object at point in time X

Tags: javers

Is it possible to easily query the state of an object from the JaVers repository as shadow/snapshot at a given time X?

Use case:
We have been logging changes to employee data with JaVers for 3 years. Now we would like a list of all employees who worked in the accounting department on 01.08.2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such queries, Javers stores snapshots of objects and a snapshot is saved when you change an object.
So all you can do is to query for objects **changed** in a given period:

```
QueryBuilder.byClass(Employee).from(...).to(...)
```